# Using encryption with Hadoop

Tags: encryption, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

The Cloudera documentation says that Hadoop does not support [on disk encryption](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Introduction+to+Hadoop+Security).  Would it be possible to use hardware encrypted hard drives with Hadoop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have mounted a file system on the drive then Hadoop can use the drive. HDFS stores its data in the normal OS file system. Hadoop will not know whether the drive is encrypted or not and it will not care.

Answer (score 7):

[eCryptfs](http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs) can be used to do per-file encryption on each individual Hadoop node.  It's rather tedious to setup, but it certainly can be done.

[Gazzang](http://www.gazzang.com) offers [a turnkey commercial solution](http://blog.gazzang.com/securing-big-data/) built on top of eCryptfs to secure "big data" through encryption, and partners with several of the Hadoop and NoSQL vendors.

> Gazzang's cloud-based Encryption Platform for Big Data helps
>   organizations transparently encrypt data stored in the cloud or on
>   premises, using advanced key management and process-based access control
>   lists, and helping meet security and compliance requirements.

*Full disclosure: I am one of authors and current maintainers of [eCryptfs](http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs).  I am also [Gazzang's](http://www.gazzang.com) Chief Architect and a lead developer.*

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop doesn't directly support encryption, though a compression codec can be used used for encryption/decryption. [Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg06222.html) are more details about encryption and HDFS.

Regarding h/w based encryption, I think Hadoop should be able to work on it. As Spike mentioned, HDFS is like any other Java application and stores it's data in the normal OS file systems. FYI, MapR uses Direct I/O for better HDFS performance.

Answer (score 0):

See also Intel's Rhino. Not open source yet...

https://github.com/intel-hadoop/project-rhino/
https://hadoop.intel.com/pdfs/IntelEncryptionforHadoopSolutionBrief.pdf

Comment: I talked to Intel at StrataConf CA this year and I'm pretty sure they aren't planning to open source it (they are selling it.)